# ios Swift parse query avoiding duplicate objects

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am querying a class in my parse server. `let query = PFQuery(classname: posts)` `query.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.friendArray)` friend array is an array that i have containing all of the usernames of the current users friends. The problem is that if a friend posted more than once, their username appears multiple times in the post class, so the query returns duplicate usernames. How can I avoid this. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you get the same post more than once or when you combine all of the sending users from all of the posts you have duplicates?

Comment: Im just trying to get a list of friends that have posts (not interested in how many posts or what the posts are). But when one of the friends has more than one posts its showing their name for each post they have.

Comment: create an array of usernames from the posts and then load that array into a set.

Comment: doess that ruin the order of the array ?

Comment: You haven't specified any sorting in the query that you have shown, so I assumed that the order of your friends array wasn't important.  You can either use an NSOrderedSet or if you just want alphabetical order, sort the data once you turn the set back into an array.

Comment: will give that a try